# Fail to fit my ML model due to Tensor conversion error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I've done some preprocessing on my dataset and tried to fit my ML model but it returns this following error message: "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor)."

The original dataset looks like this:

```
Size   Version    Count   TimeStamp    Amount   Label
319       1        31    2019-03-21     321       1
482       2        91    2014-09-28     912       2
```

The label column is my Y and the rest of the columns are the features(Xs). I normalized the size, count, and amount columns before I fed my data into the ML model. Here's my code:

```
numeric_features = ['Size', 'Count', 'Amount']
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3) # train-test split

# create normalizer based on train data
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(train_df[numeric_features].values)
# Apply normalizer
train_df[numeric_features] = normalizer(train_df[numeric_features].values)

train_X = train_df.iloc[:, :-1]
train_Y = pd.get_dummies(train_df.Label, prefix='Label')

# reshape X data
train_X = np.array(train_X)
train_X = np.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0],1,train_X.shape[1]))
train_Y = np.array(train_Y)


# Create a model
model_cnn = keras.Sequential()
model_cnn.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu'))
model_cnn.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model_cnn.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


model_cnn.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model 
epochs = 25
batch_size = 16

# This line throws an error.
history = model_cnn.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I couldn't figure out which part was causing the error. I wonder if it's because of the normalization. When I normalize the numeric columns, each cell has this type of value:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.12194966>.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your using dataframe so you going to have arrays of arrays you can solve some parties calling `.to_numpy()` in the dataframe but in some cases this will give you a numpy array of numpy arrays, So I recommend to call `np.asarray()` and not `np.array` in the last step of preparation

Comment: Thanks. But it still returns the same error message.

Comment: also the normalizer return a tensor so you maybe have some array of tensor, try to ensure yourself that all the data is only a single array of any dimension but a single one